# Utility to convert web page into .mobi or .pdf (for Kindle)?

Tags: pdf, kindle, mobi

I'd like some automated method of converting the following URL into a format I can read on my Kindle (i.e. .mobi or PDF).

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/meek/)

The output would have to have the first level of articles included (about 10 blog entries).

Comment: Caliber can convert html to .mobi and .pdf, and can sync with many readers as well, don't know how automated you can make it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) works well to convert files into .mobi format.

Answer (score 2):

[SendToReader](http://sendtoreader.com/) is a bookmarklet (javascript as a bookmark) that does this for you without you needing to download the webpage.